# Intra-Process Communication between Components in Container

Tags: ros, ros2, icp, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to take advantage of Intra Process Comms (IPC) when starting nodes in a container? I've made an example, trying to made a basic subscriber and publisher and looking at the pointer address, it seems as though it only works when "manually" composing.

This just seems surprising given the text in the [composable nodes tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Composition.html), which seems to indicate manually composing should somehow be "equivalent" to the container route. Especially given that manually composing using a multi-threaded executor also works fine.

Find the demo project [here](https://github.com/mnissov/ipc_demo). The following example outputs are directly taken from this.

### Example Outputs

#### Expected

With multi-threaded executor

```
$ ros2 run ipc_demo manual_composition 
[INFO] [1642518288.545003595] [ipc_talker]: Count: 0    Addr: 0x7f1dbc001300
[INFO] [1642518288.545393895] [ipc_listener]: Count: 0  Addr: 0x7f1dbc001300
[INFO] [1642518289.544906771] [ipc_talker]: Count: 1    Addr: 0x7f1dbc001400
[INFO] [1642518289.544989777] [ipc_listener]: Count: 1  Addr: 0x7f1dbc001400
[INFO] [1642518290.545010214] [ipc_talker]: Count: 2    Addr: 0x7f1dbc0032c0
[INFO] [1642518290.545243590] [ipc_listener]: Count: 2  Addr: 0x7f1dbc0032c0
[INFO] [1642518291.545039618] [ipc_talker]: Count: 3    Addr: 0x7f1dbc003f80
[INFO] [1642518291.545282153] [ipc_listener]: Count: 3  Addr: 0x7f1dbc003f80
[INFO] [1642518292.544973975] [ipc_talker]: Count: 4    Addr: 0x7f1db0001740
[INFO] [1642518292.545166314] [ipc_listener]: Count: 4  Addr: 0x7f1db0001740
```

Pointer addresses are the same, so should be working as expected.

#### Container

```
$ ros2 launch ipc_demo composition.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/morten/.ros/log/2022-01-18-16-04-58-690321-agrirobot-44101
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [component_container-1]: process started with pid [44117]
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518299.060037442] [two_nodes]: Load Library: /home/morten/temp_ws/install/ipc_demo/lib/libtalker_component.so
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518299.061590715] [two_nodes]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<composition::Talker>
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518299.061656586] [two_nodes]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<composition::Talker>
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/talker' in container '/two_nodes'
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518299.068096064] [two_nodes]: Load Library: /home/morten/temp_ws/install/ipc_demo/lib/liblistener_component.so
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518299.068447676] [two_nodes]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<composition::Listener>
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518299.068460910] [two_nodes]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<composition::Listener>
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/listener' in container '/two_nodes'
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518300.067406025] [talker]: Count: 0    Addr: 0x557f63f68960
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518300.067869433] [listener]: Count: 0  Addr: 0x557f63e42fd0
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518301.067393044] [talker]: Count: 1    Addr: 0x557f63e04720
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518301.067703912] [listener]: Count: 1  Addr: 0x557f64035980
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518302.067380956] [talker]: Count: 2    Addr: 0x557f64053c20
[component_container-1] [INFO] [1642518302.067666810] [listener]: Count: 2  Addr: 0x557f63e42fd0
```

Different pointer addresses between corresponding talker/listener message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394520/intra-process-communication-between-components-in-container/) by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2022-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Way down the road found a way to make it work, no one's responded so I'll post my own answer. See here, an example launch file which accomplishes my desired goal.

```
import launch
from launch_ros.actions import ComposableNodeContainer
from launch_ros.descriptions import ComposableNode


def generate_launch_description():
    container = ComposableNodeContainer(
        name="two_nodes",
        namespace="",
        package="rclcpp_components",
        executable="component_container",
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                package="ipc_demo",
                plugin="composition::Talker",
                name="talker",
                extra_arguments=[{"use_intra_process_comms": True}],
            ),
            ComposableNode(
                package="ipc_demo",
                plugin="composition::Listener",
                name="listener",
                extra_arguments=[{"use_intra_process_comms": True}],
            ),
        ],
        output="screen",
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([container])
```

---

Originally posted by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) with karma: 198 on 2022-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2022-04-05**:
Is `ipc_demo` your personal package? I'm wondering how you handled any modifications to CPP source (possibly from `composition` demos) to adapt it to intra process?